# I get an error with my INSERT for no apparent reason

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I wrote this INSERT with multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO WAREHOUSES (WAREHOUSE_ID, LOCATION)
VALUES (10, "Aguascalientes, Aguascalientes"),
       (20, "Mexicali, Baja California"),
       (30, "La Paz, Baja California Sur"),
       (40, "San Francisco de Campeche, Campeche"),
       (50, "Tuxtla Gutiérrez, Chiapas");
```

And I get the next error:

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 1 del comando -
INSERT INTO WAREHOUSES (WAREHOUSE_ID, LOCATION)
VALUES (10, "Aguascalientes, Aguascalientes"),
       (20, "Mexicali, Baja California"),
       (30, "La Paz, Baja California Sur"),
       (40, "San Francisco de Campeche, Campeche"),
       (50, "Tuxtla Gutiérrez, Chiapas")
Error en la línea de comandos : 2 Columna : 46
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I am comfused about this because, after checking many sources, it's clear to me that the INSERT itself is not incorrectly written.

Comment: You use Oracle (according to error message you got), and - *apparent reason* in this case is you, who didn't follow INSERT statement's **syntax** but tried to "invent" your own. On the other hand, to be fair, Oracle 23c allows such a syntax, but you aren't using it, are you? Basically, if you do read documentation, read the one which is valid for your database version.